# Visual Studio 2015: Brand New Universal app, won't even compile. Why am I missing System reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I wanted to try to make a Windows Universal app, but straight out of the starting gate, the template will not compile. Please refer to image below.  It is a missing system reference.  This is not the case when I try the same thing on my surface.  Do I have a bad install?   I have repaired and also resetsettings. I have also installed the standalone APK for windows 10.  There is not a lot on this topic on google, I ask for advice on what I should attempt next?

For your infomation, if I start a new project under Windows Universal app (windows 8.1), it does compile.

[image: Brand New Windows Universal app]

Comment: As Cristian is asking, what version of windows do you have installed? Also do the errors go away if you right click ont he solution and restore nuget packages?

Comment: I am on windows 10;  I am not currently updating VS to update 3.   I also exported the settings from my surface pro, which is working.   Between those two, maybe it will work?

Comment: I am trying the solutions documented [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1617801/newly-created-universal-app-projects-dont-work)

Comment: There are a lot of warnings about nuget packages in your screenshot. Have you tried deleting all the packages under "C:\Users\Brian\.nuget" and restore them again? Also please make sure you've add "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" package in your project.

Comment: I uninstalled vs and reinstalled it and not having much luck..   However,  I this is the error messages from the nuget package install of  Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform that keeps failing

Comment: Please look at this error message on the nugut install:  
Install-Package : System.IO 4.0.10 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COMPLETELY UNINSTALL VISUAL STUDIO
goto c:\programdata\package cache
move all from package cache to a new folder
run this powershell script 
$app = Get-WmiObject  -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Version = '14.0.23506'"

```
 foreach ($app in $app) {
   $app.Uninstall()
 }
```

install Visual studio

goto folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows Root\Windows UAP\1033

Go into folders BlankApplication, ClassLibrary, RunTimeComponent, UnitTestApp and modify the .vstemplate using a program under admin mode

Look for

```
package id="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" version="5.1.0" skipAssemblyReferences="false"
```

and change to the latest version number, in this case 5.2.2

```
package id="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" version="5.2.2" skipAssemblyReferences="false"
```

I would recommend you start visual studio using   devenv /ResetSettings

move the package cache back and do not replace the files.   You will have around 8 folders left in old package cache that are duplicates.

I am curious if I could have used  devenv /ResetSkipPkgs  at the beginning of this mess and fixed it..

oh well, I will never know now.